# При подгрузке данных старые данные не отображаются

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, возникла очень своеобразного рода проблема. На главную страницу сайта, данные при нажатии на ссылку меню подгружаются в блок при помощи AJAX. Все как бы идет как нужно. Но при прямом доступе к странице которая подгружается, выдает только тот материал который подгружаться должен, получается что пользователь видит не полный сайт как он должен выглядит при подгрузке а только часть. Суть вопроса такова. Как сделать так, что бы когда был POST запрос к странице аяксом выводилась одна часть, а если из строк браузера то выводилась страница полностью ?Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - проверять `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
    == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    //Пришел асинхронный запрос - выводим только обновляемую часть контента
}
else {
//Выводим весь контент
}
```

Правда, при некоторых настройках сервер может не заполнять `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`. В этом случае, остается только использовать дополнительный параметр `$_GET` or `$_POST` и ориентироваться на него.

Answer (score 0):

Если $_GET - отдаём всё, если $_POST - отдаём часть, так будет проще, да и лишних траблов с HTTP_X_REQUEST не будет